# How to get diff between two tar.gz

Tags: bash, debian, tar

I have two archive 1.tar.gz (containing hello.txt) and 2.tar.gz (containing hello.txt and helloworld.txt).

I would get the diff between this two tar.gz. The output should be helloworld.txt.

I've tried with tis command :

```
diff <(tar -tvf 1.tar.gz | sort) <(tar -tvf 2.tar.gz | sort)
```

but the output was wrong. I've got this result :

```
< drwxr-xr-x user/user         0 2016-12-09 23:29 1/
< -rw-r--r-- user/user       344 2016-12-09 23:29 1/hello.txt.gpg
---
> drwxr-xr-x user/user         0 2016-12-09 23:27 2/
> -rw-r--r-- user/user       344 2016-12-09 23:27 2/hello.txt.gpg
> -rw-r--r-- user/user       363 2016-12-09 23:27 2/helloworld.txt.gpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also works:

```
$ diff <(tar -tvf 1.tar.gz | rev | cut -d\/ -f1 | rev) <(tar -tvf 2.tar.gz | rev | cut -d\/ -f1 | rev)
1a2
> helloworld.txt.gpg
```

Further explanation:

The following: `| rev | cur -d\/ -f1 | rev` is a quick way of getting just the filename out of a full path.